# IS Maven needed to use spring tool suite

Tags: spring, maven, installation, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Can any one please tell me is it necessar to have maven installed before using Spring tool Suite(mine is version 3.4) I think its not if version is 3.2 or below

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse/STS comes with an internal maven implementation. So you do not need to have an external maven installation.